# Excel Bug in Instr

Tags: excel

I think there's a bug in InStr(), Could anyone confirm it?

For instance,

Scenario 1, `keyword = "1392WG"` and `searchString = "11392WG"`, then if you use `InStr(1, searchString, keyword, 1)`, the results will end up `1`. But if the `searchString = "31392WG"`, then the results will be `2`.

Could anyone test it?

`Sub test()

```
Updated_Date = "2016-10-10"  'Date might need to change (values after equation, remember to add it between "")
LastRow_Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastRow_Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For x = 3 To 3

    DU_ID = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value 'Cells(x, 2) might need to change
    sting_DU_ID = UCase(CStr(DU_ID))

    For y = 374 To 375
        compare_DU_ID = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 2).Value 'Cells(y, 2) might need to change
        string_compare_DU_ID = UCase(CStr(compare_DU_ID))

            If InStr(1, string_compare_DU_ID, "L4L", 1) >= 1 Then
                If string_compare_DU_ID = sting_DU_ID Then 'If L4L in compare_DU_ID, then DU_ID definitely equals to compare_DU_ID
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date '1. Cells(y, 97) might need to change, depending on which contract date you want to update
                End If
            ElseIf InStr(1, string_compare_DU_ID, sting_DU_ID, 1) = 1 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date
            ElseIf InStr(1, sting_DU_ID, string_compare_DU_ID, 1) = 1 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date
            End If
    Next
Next
```

End Sub

`

Comment: I'm getting 2 for both of them.

Comment: I don't get that, I get 2 for both.

Comment: But if I use this code `ElseIf InStr(1, searchString , keyword , 1) = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date` Then the value of cell in Sheet2 will be updated

Comment: We'd have to see the rest of your code and some sample data that reproduces the issue.  All of our tests don't result in the bug you're experiencing.  My guess is that it's not a problem with InStr(), but a problem with the defined searchString in your code.

Comment: @tigeravatar Hi, I edited the problem, and paste on my code, could you please refer it. Many thanks!

Comment: You are doing three test that all result in the same output.  Are you certain it is that offending line that is causing the errant output.  You need to step through your code as it is running or put some other outputs to see which part of the IF statement is returning True.

Comment: @ScottCraner I use F8 to debug, and none of the if statement was executed ..

Comment: The code works as expected when I create some sample data to test it out.  I am unable to produce any bugs, nor replicate the issue you've described.  Can you please provide sample data that reproduces this issue?  As for your comment to Scott, if none of the IF statements are firing, then the code isn't writing anything to the sheet.  My guess is that the date is already in that cell, or the date is getting written there from another source (like a different macro)

Comment: Should they have executed?  By your values that is what is expected.  Since the Instr should have returned 2.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, it returns 2, but I don't know why either `ElseIf` was being executed.

Comment: You said neither were being executed.  My guess is you have more code that is setting the value outside of the loop provided.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, in theory, neither were being executed, but the date was updated, so one of the `ElseIf` code was being executed, but when I use F8, it didn't step into either `ElseIf`